# Creating users in Google Apps from Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I am using Google Apps Script to create users in Google Apps in bulk via spreadsheet

my spreadsheet has 4 columns where i have firstname, lastname, emailId, and password, as these are required to create users.

My following script works fine and create users without issue, however it stops at a point if any user already exists, and does not move forward to attempt other ones in spreadsheet.

I want it to loop through the whole spreadsheet, skip the ones that already exists, and create the ones who don't

Any help is appreciated.

```
function createUsers() {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Create Users")
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  for(i=1; i <values.length; i++)
  {

    var fName = values[i][0]
    var lName = values[i][1]
    var email = values[i][2]
    var password = values[i][3]
    var status = values[i][4]
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert({
      "primaryEmail": email,
       "password": password, 
      "orgUnitPath": "/MDM Testing",
      "name": {
        "familyName": lName,
        "givenName": fName

  }
      })

    Logger.log(user);


  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add If condition to check duplicate user as follows.

```
function createUsers() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Create Users")
      var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

      for(i=1; i <values.length; i++)
      {

        var fName = values[i][0]
        var lName = values[i][1]
        var email = values[i][2]
        var password = values[i][3]
        var status = values[i][4]
        // Check user exist or not by email address.
        var userFromDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email);
        if(email != userFromDirectory.primaryEmail){
          var user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert({
            "primaryEmail": email,
            "password": password, 
            "orgUnitPath": "/MDM Testing",
            "name": {
            "familyName": lName,
            "givenName": fName

          }
         })
          Logger.log(user);

        } // end of if




      }}
```

Comment: thanks much, i tried this and it gives error "Resource Not Found: userKey" at  var userFromDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email); and then does not move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var userFromDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.list.name
```

instead of

```
var userFromDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email);
```